# Node Js soap package

Tags: node.js, soap

I am using node soap package and trying to call a WSDL function by sending request to it. The function is working fine when I tried it through SoapUI client. I want to execute it through my node application. I have used 'soap' node package in the following manner:

```
soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            client.ProcessOrderRequest(exampleJsonRequest, function(error, processOrderResult, body) {
                console.log(error)
            })
        }
})
```

I saw an example on the package's documentation that we can send json data to the function while in  SoapUI I am sending xml data and it works. The same is not working in node code.

It is giving an error as below:

```
Fault: 
   { faultcode: 500,
     faultstring: 'Invalid XML',
     detail: 'Error: Non-whitespace before first tag.\nLine: 0\nColumn: 1\nChar: \u001f',
     statusCode: 500 }
```

I tried sending XML string and it is still not working. What can be issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem looking for the problem in the request, but it was really on the **response** from the server.  Log your response from the server and double-check it is a valid XML response.
The issue comes when your client get the answer and try to deserialize the XML response to a JSON object, and since it is not valid, the 'Invalid XML' is issued.

In my case, the response "404: not found: /" was sent as plain text instead of a XML message.  When I changed to

```
"<error>404: not found: /</error>"
```

the issue was solved, and then I realized the root cause of the problem was in the WSDL binding definition.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like exampleJsonRequest is invalid format. Please review your soap request and exampleJsonRequest.

Comment: I tried with an simple json like {"test": "Test"} in place of exampleJsonRequest and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `client.lastRequest;`.  It is a property. It will print the request in xml format. After printing the requested xml; compare it with the xml request in SOAP. There might be the difference in the xml files. 
Probably the error might be because of two same xmlns attributes for requested input variables. This might be because of SOAP package (which created the requested xml). There is another approach to add arguments. Use [XML String for the args](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap#example-with-xml-string-for-the-args). Go to the link and try creating the argument using xml string.

Later re-verify the requested xml with the new xml string approach.

I think this will be useful for other users who are still facing the same problem. Please add your queries if you are still facing the issue.